# WebAPI not returning HTTP 406 and giving unacceptable content

Tags: http, asp.net-web-api

I'm writing a WebAPI application and trying to remove XML. I have removed the `XmlFormatter` but if I make a request with `Accept: application/xml` I still get a `200` response with an `application/json` body. Why is this? How do I ensure that I get back a 406 error instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebAPI desperately want to return a response, so the default content negotiator falls back to the one available when no match was found.

You'll have to provide `excludeMatchOnTypeOnly`:

```
var negotiator = new DefaultContentNegotiator(excludeMatchOnTypeOnly: true);
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IContentNegotiator), negotiator);
```

At least, according to [this 2012 blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/05/14/asp-net-web-api-updates-may-14.aspx).

Comment: I guess that this should work? But it isn't, and I can't figure out why.